# How to filter array value in my case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to push a value into an array based on some conditions.

I have something like

```
var newEmplyee = [];
$scope.employees = [{'id':1, 'new':true},{'id':2, 'new':false}{'id':3, 'new':false}];
newEmployee = $scope.employees.filter(function(emp){
    if(emp.new) {
        return emp.id
    }
})
```

However, when I `console.log(newEmployee)`, I got an object like

```
{'id':1, 'new':true}
```

instead of just id `[1]`.

I am not sure what went wrong here. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Satpal the first function would only need to be: `function(emp) { return emp.new; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use combination of [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> Array.prototype.filter(): The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function
>
> Array.prototype.map(): The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

*Code*

```
var newEmployee = $scope.employees.filter(function(emp) {
    return emp.new; //Filter new employess
}).map(function(emp) {
    return emp.id; //Get Its ID
})
```

Additionally: Missing `,` after `{'id':2, 'new':false}`

```
$scope.employees = [{'id':1, 'new':true},{'id':2, 'new':false}{'id':3, 'new':false}];
```

Should be

```
    $scope.employees = [{
    'id': 1,
    'new': true
}, {
    'id': 2,
    'new': false
} {
    'id': 3,
    'new': false
}];
```

```js
var employees = [{'id':1, 'new':true},{'id':2, 'new':false},{'id':3, 'new':false}];

var newEmployee = employees.filter(function(emp) {
    return emp.new; //Filter new employess
}).map(function(emp) {
    return emp.id; //Get Its ID
});

console.log(newEmployee);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the filtered object.From  your method return emp object instead of emp.id .

```
var newEmplyee = [];
$scope.employees = [{'id':1, 'new':true},{'id':2, 'new':false},{'id':3, 'new':false}];
newEmployee = $scope.employees.filter(function(emp){
    if(emp.new) {
        return emp;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter iterator doesn't change array, but it select something based on some condition. So what you want is mix of **filter** and **map** iterators.

```
var newEmplyee = [];
$scope.employees = [{'id':1, 'new':true},{'id':2, 'new':false},{'id':3, 'new':false}];
newEmployee = $scope.employees.filter(function(emp){
    return emp.new;
}).map(function(a){
   return a.id;
});
```

Also you can solve your problem by using **reduce** iterator.

```
var newEmplyee = [];
$scope.employees = [{'id':1, 'new':true},{'id':2, 'new':false},{'id':3, 'new':false}];
newEmployee = $scope.employees.reduce(function(container, e){
 if(e.new)
   container.push(e.id);
 return container;
}, []);
```

Read this nice [article](http://www.elijahmanor.com/reducing-filter-and-map-down-to-reduce/) about **reduce** and **filter**.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [{'id':1, 'new':true},{'id':2, 'new':false},{'id':3, 'new':false}] | filter:{'new':true}
```